# Wordpress to use Drupal users' credentials

Tags: wordpress, drupal, authentication, user-registration

I have both Wordpress and Drupal installed on two domains. I want the users that register via Wordpress to be stored in Drupal's user table. Also, any login attempts should be checked against Drupal's database.

I don't have a lot of experience with either (though I'm fairly confident in my PHP skills). I am not looking for a way to mirror the users, but to actually tell Wordpress to use Drupal's database.

I think I have to rewrite the login and register methods on Wordpress. Am I wrong? And what's the best way to do this? (what files do I need to go into)?

Comment: You will have better luck here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware there is a special section dedicated to Wordpress. :)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to tell Wordpress to use Drupal's entire database as it'll just create a lot more headaches. You're better off loading something like Drupal's boostrap and attempting to call the registration functionality, this again would cause more issues.

Is there a particular reason preventing you from using one system? Migration plugins/modules exist for both CMS'.

I'm sure others have come across the same issues.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/
[Wordpress and Drupal SSO/Single Sign On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725071/wordpress-and-drupal-sso-single-sign-on)
[How to register a user to Drupal 6.x without using the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509342/how-to-register-a-user-to-drupal-6-x-without-using-the-api)